# how to show more than 1 table to one view

Tags: mysql, vue.js, laravel-5

i have 4 table in my database there is MataUang,lokasi, pelanggan, item. They don't have any relationship at all.
is it possible to get all of data from tables and give it to one view then i want spread it to bootstrap table with vue as front end and laravel as backend[image: example of view]

at first i think this will worked, but didn't.`

```
    View::make('index')
->with('MataUang', MataUang::all())
->with('Lokasi', Lokasi::all())
->with('Pelanggan', Pelanggan::all()); 
->with('Item', Item::all()); 
    }
```

because in vue js as front end it can't worked.

Comment: are they associated to each other?

Comment: no, they dont have any associated

Comment: then u have to get these separately through eloquent.

Comment: it can't because i use vue js as front end